# android studio firebasemessagingservice pendingintent not working in kill mode

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

everything works as well when the app already run, but in kill mode, nothing happened when i click on the notification, the click only remove the notification with no crashing

```
JSONObject oData = hashClass.HashToJson(new HashMap<>(data));

Class<?> c = Class.forName(Objects.requireNonNull(notification.getClickAction()));
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
            intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION, oData.toString());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "kill mode"?

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag. That tag is used for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: @DavidWasser, kill mode means when the app is totally stopped (no services in background and not minimized), i used android studio tag to attract the attention of those who work in android studio, because they may face the same problem before

Comment: Android Studio is a product, the development environment. If you tag your question with `android` this will attract Android developers.

Comment: If you "force stop" the app, Android will not start it again until you manually start it (by tapping the app icon on the HOME screen). Have you "force stopped" the app?

Comment: @DavidWasser in main activity in onBackPressed i use an intent to close the app because its not the launcher activity (intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);)

Comment: Please explain. Normally you don't need to do this. Please edit your question and show the code.